# When a global digital services company withdrows from the market of a specific country, does it affects the local tax income?

Tags: macroeconomics, taxation, nonexpert

So, here are the conditions:

1. We have a country X
2. We have a company "Example Inc.", which provides some digital service in X. Let's say "Example Inc." is a game development company.
3. "Example Inc." doesn't have any employees in X.
4. For some reason, "Example Inc." decides to stop selling their games in X.

The question is "Does this decision of Example Inc. affects tax income in X"?
I've seen two opinions on this:

1. When "Example Inc." stops providing services in X, it reduces the volume of the corresponding market. Reduction in market volume leads to the reduction of the tax base and, eventually, to the reduction of tax income. The effect from a single company is hardly noticeable, but if multiple companies do the same thing, tax income reduction will be significant.
2. It won't affect tax income, because people will just spend their money on other things. "Example Inc." doesn't have any employees in X, so their decision won't even affect the job market in X.

I wasn't able to find any creditable source on this matter, and I'm lacking knowledge in this field to make my own decision.

Comment: The immediate effect should be decline in tax revenue from sales tax / GST channel. In the medium to long run how things pan out depends on a whole lot of variables.

Comment: @Dayne could you point out the most important factors to take in the account in such situations?